# Retrieving multiple tags via beautifulsoup css selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to provide multiple arguments to beautifulsoup's `select` method?

I'm retrieving data via `soup.select('div[class^="TypeA"]'`. This fetches me all the divs where classes match the pattern `TypeA`. I'm interested in retrieving, in addition, another div where `class="TypeB"` (exact match).

Now I can possibly do this in two separate passes, e.g. something like:

```
r = requests.get(jurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
list1 = []
#get typeA divs
for div in soup.select('div[class^="TypeA"]'):
    t = [text for text in div.stripped_strings]
    list1.append(t)
list2 = []
#get typeB divs
for div in soup.select('div[class^="TypeB"]'):
    t = [text for text in div.stripped_strings]
    list2.append(t)
#combine the two into tuples. Both lists are of the same size
list3 = []
count = 0
for item in list1:
    list3.append((item,list2[count]))
    count += 1    
print list3
```

But is it possible to do it in a single pass? Going through the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it's not immediately obvious how this can be done.

Comment: You can use `zip` function `for div1, div2 in zip(soup.select('div[class^="TypeA"]'), soup.select('div[class^="TypeB"]')):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
soup.select('div[class^="TypeA"], div[class^="TypeB"]')
```

Use `,` to use multiple selectors

[CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[image]

Comment: What is this? why two `typeA` classes?

Comment: Thanks again 宏杰李!